# A rigid bar suspended from $2$ wires, given the coordinates of the centre of the bar, find the lengths of the two wires

Tags: geometry, circles, classical-mechanics

I'm not sure whether this is a geometry or mechanics problem, and I'm not too hot on either so either way I need help :) I think it's pure geometry. Also I am not really sure how to formulate this problem, so again, please bear with me, this is really not my area of expertise.

I have a bar of fixed length B suspended from two strings, of lengths $R_1$ and $R_2$, fixed at their other ends to two fixed points, $P_1$, $P_2$, which lie on a horizontal line, and are a fixed horizontal distance apart, $S$. For convenience I've defined these fixed points as at positions $(0,0)$ and $(S, 0)$. $R_1$ and $R_2$ are not fixed, they can be varied.

I want to calculate what the lengths of the two strings, $R_1$ and $R_2$, need to be in order for the centre of the bar to lie at some specific location, which we will call $(x,y)$

In other word I want a function $F(x,y) \implies (R_1,R_2)$

I understand that there maybe more than one solution.

I have tried to solve this by looking at the formula for the circles centred on $P_1$ and $P_2$, and $(x,y)$ of radii $R_1$ and $R_2$ and $B$, and then attempting the solve these simultaneously; however my maths is just not up to it.

I've also tried to solve this mechanically by analysis the tensions in the strings assuming the bar has some mass $M$, and then working back form the tension to the angles the strings have to make with the bar, and then solve that lot simultaneously to find the string lengths that would give those angles; but again my maths just can't cope.

Can anyone assist me please?

[Simple Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9O4c.png)

Comment: The orientation of the bar is not given so there are infinitely many possible values for R1 and R2 depending on the angle the bar makes with the horizontal.  You could calculate the lengths in terms of that angle.

Comment: The bar "hangs", is its orientation not governed by gravity and R1 and R2?

Also, if there are infinitely many possible values then great, this is a partcal probelm I'm trytign to somve, so any one of those infinite answers would be great.

Comment: Also, for some positions, a given orientation of the bar is not possible, whereas for some other orientation there might be a solution: Imagine the bar hanging vertically below P1 there is only one solution for this (x,y) location, and that is with the bar oriented vertically, with 0 tension on R2 If we were to require the bar to be horizontal for example no (x,y) position with x = 0 would be possible.

So by specifying the orientation I reduce the range of soluble values of (x,y)

Comment: Also, given this is practical problem, and R1 and R2 will have some "current" length, the solution with the smallest total difference between the current R1 and R2 and the target R1 and R2 would be the best solution.

Comment: $R_1$ and $R_2$ can have many different values but $R_1-R_2 = \sqrt {B^2-S^2}$ if you want both strings to be hanging to its fullest length (esp. given $P1$ and $P2$ are fixed and so $S$ is fixed). Please define those assumptions.

Comment: "if you want both strings to be hanging to its fullest length" - I'm not sure I understand, how can a string *hang* to anything other than its fullest length?

Comment: Also it might help to think of this as a mechanics problem. When I setup a real world test rig, and set the string lengths to be two arbitrary values, the bar comes to rest at one spot, therefore it appears that for 2 string lengths there is exactly one solution for (x,y)

Comment: @SimonHartley - Say you are hanging two strings (S1, S2) from the ceiling at $3$ unit distance from each other. Tied to them is a bar of length $5$ unit. Say, length $S1$ is $1$ and $S2$ is $3$. How will they hang? What happens when $S1$ is $1$ and $S2$ is $5$.

Comment: Ah, the strings must be in tension, I guess that's an assumption I didn't state :)

And also the length B will always be < S

Comment: In general, for any angle at which the bar rests, the wires have to be attached at angles such that all the forces and moments balance out. This is a complicated system. You might be able to solve it for arbitrary lengths $R_1$ and $R_2,$ which then will let you find the coordinates $x$ and $y$ as function of $R_1$ and $R_2$ you may or may not be able to solve that system of equations for $R_1$ and $R_2$ in terms of $x$ and $y.$

Comment: Do you think it might be solvable for x and y *computationally* i.e. by some *iterative* *simulation* like approach? (I have no idea if these are meaningful maths words, sorry)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: StatesOfEquilibrium]
$\underline{\mathrm{Introduction}}$

We assume that, by now, you have realized that this problem cannot be solved using geometry alone. As @David.k has pointed out in his comment, the equilibrium of coplanar forces and moments acting on the bar must also be taken into account. However, we only need to bother about the directions and not the magnitude of these quantities.

Now, if your knowledge of Engineering Mechanics is as good as that of mathematics, you have to have blind faith in us, when we state that three coplanar forces acting on a body in equilibrium concur, i.e. meet at a point. For instance, the bar shown in $\mathrm{Fig. 1}$ is not in equilibrium, because there is a counterclockwise moment proportional to the distance $p_x$, which pulls one of its end (i.e. $A$) downwards and pushes its other end (i.e. $B$) upwards.  This moment strives to change the position of the bar by adjusting the strings until the point $P$ lands somewhere on the vertical line passing through its center of gravity. When the system attains its stability, it may look like the one shown in  $\mathrm{Fig. 2}$

We are going to exploit the above-mentioned phenomenon to concoct a method to determine the length of the two strings to hang a bar of given length ($2b$) from two hooks fixed a known distance $d_1+d_2$ apart, so that the midpoint of the bar coincides with a given point in space, for instance $O$. This method works if and only if lengths $b, d_1, d_2$, and $h$ are greater than zero. The case, in which $d_1=d_2=0$, has to be analysed using common sense.

$\underline{\mathrm{Method}}$

To understand the derivation of this method, you need to polish up your knowledge of Coordinate Geometry. Without loss of generality, we assume that the midpoint $O$ of the bat lies at the origin of the Cartesian coordinate system. As shown in $\mathrm{Fig. 2}$, the two lines representing the strings have the same $y$-intercept, if their point of intersection $P$ lies on the $y$-axis, which is the vertical line passing through the CG of the bar. The only unknown in this system is $\phi$, the bar’s tilt to the horizontal - negative $x$-axis to be precise. Please note that $\phi$ is always seen as a positive quantity and. measured clockwise to avoid ambiguity. Therefore, when we get a negative angle as the answer for $\phi$, we make it positive by subtracting its absolute value from the full angle, i.e. $360^o$.

Using the points $A, B, C$, and $D$ and their coordinates depicted in the figure, we can express the equations of the strings $DA$ and $CB$ as

$$y=\space\space\space\left(\frac{h-b\sin\left(\phi\right)}{b\cos\left(\phi\right)–d_1}\right)x +  h + \left(\frac{h-b\sin\left(\phi\right)}{b\cos\left(\phi\right)–d_1}\right)d_1, \tag{String $\it{DA}$}$$

$$y=-\left(\frac{h+b\sin\left(\phi\right)}{b\cos\left(\phi\right)–d_2}\right)x +  h + \left(\frac{h+b\sin\left(\phi\right)}{b\cos\left(\phi\right)–d_2}\right)d_2. \tag{String $\it{CB}$}$$

When we equate the two $y$-intercepts of these lines, we get,
$$h + \left(\frac{h-b\sin\left(\phi\right)}{b\cos\left(\phi\right)–d_1}\right)d_1 = h + \left(\frac{h+b\sin\left(\phi\right)}{b\cos\left(\phi\right)–d_2}\right)d_2.$$

When we simplify this, we have,
$$\Big(h-b\sin\left(\phi\right)\Big)\Big(b\cos\left(\phi\right)–d_2\Big)d_1 = \Big(h+b\sin\left(\phi\right)\Big)\Big(b\cos\left(\phi\right)–d_1\Big)d_2.$$

After eliminating $\cos\left(\phi\right)$from the left-hand side of the above expression, we simplify it further to obtain the following equation of degree four in $\sin\left(\phi\right)$.

$$a_4\sin^4\left(\phi\right) + a_3\sin^3\left(\phi\right) + a_2\sin^2\left(\phi\right) + a_1\sin\left(\phi\right) + a_0 = 0, \quad\mathrm{where,} \tag{1}$$
$a_4 = b^2\left(d_1+d_2\right)^2,\space a_1 = -a_3 = 2hb\left(d_1^2-d_2^2\right),\space a_0 = - h^2\left(d_1-d_2\right)^2,\space$ and $\space a_2 = 4d_1^2d_2^2 -  a_4 – a_0$.

To solve this equation to find the values of $\phi$, you have to use numerical methods or use a tool such as Wolfram Mathematica. This equation has either four complex roots or two complex roots and two real roots. In the former case, this problem has no ($real$) solution. In the later instance, we have two mathematically valid solutions, where one of them is always positive and the other is always negative. However, only one of them leads to a system in stable equilibrium. $\mathrm{Fig. 3}$ shows an example, where we provide both mathematically valid solutions. We hope that you can visualize in this diagram why configuration shown to the right is in neutral equilibrium and, thus, making it useless in practice.

[image: Example]
In order to find out which of the two solutions leads to the instance of stable equilibrium, we need to differentiate between three possible scenarios depending on the size of $d_1$  and $d_2$. If $d_1 \lt d_2$, the stable equilibrious configuration arises from the positive solution. On the other hand, if $d_1 \gt d_2$, it is the negative solution that indicates the tilt of the bar in stable equilibrium,. The third scenario occurs when we have $d_1 = d_2$. In this special case, equation (1) breaks up into two equations as shown below. Please note that we have introduced a variable $d$ not shown in the diagrams such that $d = d_1 = d_2$.
$$ \sin^2\left(\phi\right) = 0 \qquad\rightarrow\qquad \phi_1=\phi_2=0^o \tag{2}$$
$$\sin^2\left(\phi\right) =  \left(1 - \frac{d^2}{b^2} \right) \qquad\rightarrow\qquad \phi=\pm \sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1 - \frac{d^2}{b^2}}\right) \tag{3}$$

Equation (2) gives us the two solutions, type of which we are now familiar with – the bar in stable and neutral equilibrium. Unlike in the other two scenarios, the bar is horizontal in both states of equilibrium (see $\mathrm{Fig. 4}$). Furthermore, when $b \ge d$ (see $\mathrm{Fig. 5}$), as indicated by equation (3), this scenario possesses two additional stable equilibrium states. These configurations of equilibrium are in complete agreement with the laws of mechanics, because the two strings are parallel to $y$-axis and, therefore, all three line meet at infinity as required by those laws. Equation (3) does not have real solutions when $b \lt d$.

[image: Specialcase]

We suggest that you should work out the special case, where $b, d_1, h > 0$ and $d_2 = 0$, to test yourself the knowledge you have acquired by reading this answer. As we have already noted, the case of $d_1=d_2=0$ cannot be analysed using this method, because in this particular case we have $a_4 = a_3 = a_2 = a_1 = a_0 = 0$, i.e. equation (1) vanishes. That does not mean that there is no stable configuration when $d_1=d_2=0$. On the contrary, there is a $nice$ solution. We would like to leave it to OP to find that solution.

After choosing the value of $\phi$, which gives the configuration in the state of stable equilibrium, you can use the following equations to determine the lengths of the two strings.

$$s_1 = \sqrt{\Big(b\cos\left(\phi\right)-d_1\Big)^2 + \Big(h-b\sin\left(\phi\right)\Big)^2} \tag{String $\it{DA}$}$$

$$s_2 = \sqrt{\Big(d_2-b\cos\left(\phi\right)\Big)^2 + \Big(h+b\sin\left(\phi\right)\Big)^2} \tag{String $\it{CB}$}$$

Comment: @SimonHartley Did you go through my answer, which I posted about a week ago? If you are not satisfied with it, you should have commented to express your opinion about it. If you have done so, I would have shown you how to write a program to simulate an iterative geometric construction to determine the lengths of the two wires

Comment: HI, apologies. I have been on holidays for the last few weeks. I am working my way through your answer now. Thank you so much for the effort you have put it.

Comment: "the special case, where $d_1,a,b>0$ and $d_2=0$"  -  this is when the bar is hanging vertically from C (so E and C are coincident?) 
If which case $s_2 = a - b$, and $s_1 = \sqrt{(d_1)^2 + (a + b)^2}$

Is this correct?

Comment: I have successfully implemented the above method as a python program, with a nice clean entry point that maps desired $x,y$ of the centre of the bar (with $d1$ at $(0,0)$ ) to string lengths $s_1, s_2$ for the stable equilibrium solution.

Thank you so much YNK for your assistance.

Comment: @SimonHartley I have just corrected several typos in my answer. I am apologizing for inadvertently typing $\mathbf{\mathit{a}}$ in place of  $\mathbf{\mathit{h}}$. $$ $$ Yes, you have correctly analyzed the case where $b, d_1, h \gt 0$, and $d_2 = 0$.The values you have obtained for $s_1$ and $s_2$ correspond to the case, where the bar is in stable equilibrium.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

Assuming a homogeneous mass M bar and weightless hanging wires we can solve for $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,T_1, T_2$ the static equilibrium scenario.

$$
\cases{
T_2 \cos (\beta )-T_1 \cos (\alpha )=0\\
T_1 \sin (\alpha )+T_2 \sin (\beta )-M g=0 \\
T_2 \sin (\beta +\gamma )-\frac{1}{2}M g\cos (\gamma )=0\\
R_1\cos (\alpha )+B \cos (\gamma )+R_2 \cos (\beta )-S=0\\
R_1\sin (\alpha )+B \sin (\gamma )-R_2 \sin (\beta)=0
}
$$

so giving $R_1, R_2, S, M, g$ we can obtain the sought coordinates

$$
\cases{
x = R_1 \cos (\alpha )+\frac{1}{2} B \cos (\gamma )\\
y = -R_1 \sin (\alpha )-\frac{1}{2} B \sin (\gamma )
}
$$

Follows a MATHEMATICA script to perform the calculations

```
parms = {R1 -> 2, R2 -> 1, B -> 1.5, S -> 3, g -> 10, M -> 1};
equs = T1 {-Cos[alpha], Sin[alpha]} + M g {0, -1} + T2 {Cos[beta],Sin[beta]};
p1 = {0, 0, 0};
p2 = p1 + R1 {Cos[alpha], -Sin[alpha], 0};
p3 = p2 + B {Cos[gamma], -Sin[gamma], 0};
p4 = p3 + R2 {Cos[beta], Sin[beta], 0};
equ = 1/2 Cross[(p3 - p2), M g {0, -1, 0}] + Cross[p3 - p2, T2 {Cos[beta], Sin[beta], 0}];
mom = equ[[3]];
cicl = p4 - {S, 0, 0};
equstot = Join[Join[equs, {mom}], Take[cicl, {1, 2}]];
equstot0 = equstot /. parms;
sol = NMinimize[Norm[equstot0], {alpha, beta, gamma, T1, T2}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
path = {p1, p2, p3, p4} /. sol[[2]] /. parms
line = path[[All, 1 ;; 2]]
grline = ListLinePlot[line];
{x, y} = {R1 Cos[alpha] + 1/2 B Cos[gamma], -R1 Sin[alpha] - 1/2 B Sin[gamma]} /. sol[[2]] /. parms;
grpt = Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{x, y}]}];
Show[grline, grpt]
```

[image]

Comment: I have not a clue whether this is correct or not :)

However I can use it and see if it gives the desired results. I'll let you know. Thank you.

Comment: Apologies if I'm being dim, but what are α,β,γ in the above?

α,β are the angle the strings make with the bar, and γ the angle the bar makes with the horizontal?

Comment: @DavidK It looks weird but the considered orientation for angles was: $\alpha, \gamma$ CW and $\beta$ CCW. Sorry.

Comment: So in the figure, $\gamma$ has a negative value? Now that I have checked the equation involving $\sin(\gamma),$ it all looks consistent.

Comment: The first equation is saying  the bar is in equilibrium horizontally (the two opposite horizontal components of the strings' tensions are equal and opposite).

The second is saying  the same thing for vertical forces on the bar; the vertical component of the strings' tensions equal the weight of the bar,

The third is resolving moments about the point at which R1 connects to the bar, saying the bar is not rotating.

Have I got this right so far?

What are the final two equations saying?

Comment: The fourth is saying that the bar is less or equal to S; or alternatively that the "horizontal bits" all sum to S; correct?

Oh, and is the fifth saying that the fixed ends of the strings are level?

Comment: @SimonHartley Yes. The equations' meaning is that.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far.The above hint shows how to derive X and Y for some R1 and R2, if I understand correctly. Any hint on how I use this to derive values (any valid set of values) for R1 and R2 given X and Y?